# Как произвести миграцию в Alembic?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Смотрел здесь туториал http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html 
прописал alembic revision -m "create account table" и мне создало скрипт, но поля в нем пусты, я так и не понял мне самому их заполнять или есть чудесная команда которая все сделает. В schema новая таблица есть.
Использую python, alembic, sqlalchemy, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста